# Since moving to 6.2.0+ ALL Android images do NOT work

Tags: android, image, titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

Since moving to 6.2.0+ ALL Android images do NOT work

Error:
[ERROR] :  TiDrawableReference: (pool-3-thread-1) [144,144] Problem opening stream with url /images/logo.png: Resources/images/logo.png
[ERROR] :  TiDrawableReference: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Resources/images/logo.png

Code (app.tss):
image: '/images/[image name]'

Location:
Android>images>res-[density folder] (hdpi, mdpi,xhdpi,xxhdpi,xxxhdpi)

Running on device and simulator
Galaxy S8, Genymotion Pixel +

Answer (score 2):

Known issue
https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-25284

Fixed in 6.2.2 Confirmed working